# Can on marshal a string[] to a safearray variant?

Tags: c#, vbscript, com-interop

When I marshal my function returning a `string[]` as `UnmanagedType.Struct` with `SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_ARRAY` as in

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
  [ComVisible(true)]
  [Guid("4BDC43D4-8FD7-4F58-BEE5-E57C3C144C1B")]
  public class Array
  {
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_ARRAY)]
    public string[] StringArray()
    {
      return new string[] { "foo", "bar" };
    }
  }
}
```

I was expecting to get a variant ([UnmanagedType
Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

> Struct
>      A VARIANT, which is used to marshal managed formatted classes and value types.

However the VBScript code

```
WScript.Echo TypeName(CreateObject("StackOverflow.Array").StringArray)
```

reports `String()` (which is not a `Variant()` and therefore I will get type
missmatch errors later when accesing the array).

When I change my code to either

```
public object[] ObjectArray()
{
  return new object[] { "foo", "bar" };
}

public object PlainObject()
{
  return new object[] { "foo", "bar" };
}
```

the VBScript code seems to works fine, however I would like to know why I cannot return a `string[]` and manually marshall it to a variant containing a
safearray of variants.

It seems that the `SafeArraySubType` has no effect. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because the SafeArraySubType only applies to SafeArrays.

```
MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT)]
```

Comment: I find that unlikely given http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079200/how-to-correctly-marshal-vb-script-arrays-to-and-from-a-com-component-written-in uses `UnmanagedType.Struct, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_ARRAY`.

Comment: That's because the SafeArraySubType is ignored for structs. Structs by the nature are already a "variant array" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype(v=vs.100).aspx) because they have their properties layout in sequence.